# PIVOT multiple rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have table like below. Consider the query

```
select invoice_mth, inv_amt from table xdetails
 where mobile_number=9080808080
```

data in the table

```
mobile_number   invoice_mth  inv_amt
 9080808080     2010-10        20
 9080808080     2010-11        30
 9080808080     2010-12        40
```

I have to display the data from table like below.

I want invoice months to separate each month and amt separately.

```
MOBILE_NUMBER   inv_m1   inv_m2    inv_m3   amt1    amt2    amt3
------- ----------------------------------------------------------
 9080808080    2010-10   2010-11   2010-12   20       30      40
```

to display the data like above what I have to do?

Comment: There are plenty of plenty of pivoting questions and answers on Stackoverflow.    If your situation is urgent you should read some of the threads in [this search result set](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+row+column+pivot).  The main question is, do you know the number of rows you want to pivot upfront?  Or do you need a dynamic solution?

Answer (score 3):

You could play around with the standard **PIVOT** query:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

MOBILE_NUMBER INVOICE    INV_AMT
------------- ------- ----------
   9080808080 2010-10         20
   9080808080 2010-11         30
   9080808080 2010-12         40

SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT mobile_number, invoice_mth, inv_amt FROM t
  4    ) PIVOT (MIN(invoice_mth) AS inv_mth,
  5             SUM(inv_amt) AS inv_amt
  6             FOR (invoice_mth) IN ('2010-10' AS m1, '2010-11' AS m2, '2010-12' AS m3))
  7  ORDER BY mobile_number;

MOBILE_NUMBER M1_INV_ M1_INV_AMT M2_INV_ M2_INV_AMT M3_INV_ M3_INV_AMT
------------- ------- ---------- ------- ---------- ------- ----------
   9080808080 2010-10         20 2010-11         30 2010-12         40

SQL>
```

Comment: 105 57060 36069 WCT 5.25% 5.25
105 57060 36069 Sec 194C - Contractor - Non Individual 2% PWCPL 2
105 57060 36070 Sec 194C - Contractor - Non Individual 2% PWCPL 2
105 57060 36070 WCT 5.25% 5.25
105 57060 36071 WCT 5.25% 5.25
105 57060 36072 Sec 194C - Contractor - Non Individual 2% PWCPL 2
105 57060 36072 WCT 5.25% 5.25
105 57060 36073 WCT 5.25% 5.25
105 57060 36074 WCT 5.25% 5.25
105 57060 36074 Sec 194C - Contractor - Non Individual 2% PWCPL 2

Comment: Please mark it as answered, it will help others as well.

Comment: The pivot function rocks! :)

Comment: Hi Lalith, here IN class u r passing static values, but if we want to make this values as non static(dynamic) values How can we do this. I have tried PIVOT XML but it is displaying the XML tags, not displaying in the table form. Can u provide tha solution for this..Pls I am facing problem with this issue last one week..I am very thankful for U r reply...

Comment: I understand your concern. however, for dynamic pivoting the only way I know is using PL/SQL, Tom Kyte has demonstrated an example here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42asktom-1653097.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed number of columns in the output:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d44ca/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( mobile_number, invoice_mth, inv_amt ) AS
          SELECT 9080808080, '2010-10', 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9080808080, '2010-11', 30 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9080808080, '2010-12', 40 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT mobile_number,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN invoice_mth END ) AS inv_m1,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN invoice_mth END ) AS inv_m2,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN invoice_mth END ) AS inv_m3,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN inv_amt END ) AS amt1,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN inv_amt END ) AS amt2,
       MAX( CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN inv_amt END ) AS amt3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY mobile_number ORDER BY invoice_mth ASC ) AS rn
  FROM   TABLE_NAME t
)
GROUP BY mobile_number
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d44ca/6/0)**:

```
| MOBILE_NUMBER |  INV_M1 |  INV_M2 |  INV_M3 | AMT1 | AMT2 | AMT3 |
|---------------|---------|---------|---------|------|------|------|
|    9080808080 | 2010-10 | 2010-11 | 2010-12 |   20 |   30 |   40 |
```